Use private go module with gitlab ci Auto-DevOps for auto test
I use gitlab auto dev ops to deploy my project. I have a problem with auto tests(https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/stages.html#auto-test). In my project I use a go private module.
The error is :
get "gitlab.com/xxx/libs/xxx": checking for a non-authoritative meta tag
cmd/main.go:8:2: read gitlab.com/xxx/libs/xxx/go.mod at revision xxx/v1.0.0: git ls-remote -q origin in /tmp/build/.heroku/go-path/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/xxx: exit status 128 :
    fatal : could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com' : terminal prompts disabled
Confirm that the import path has been entered correctly.
If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for more information.

I've seen that gitlab uses buildpacks and that it's possible to use a custom build pack with the BUILDPACK_URL variable.
I also saw that you could modify the git url to use basic authentication to pull a private project (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go#private-git-repos).
However, if I understand correctly, the heroku config is used to launch the application in heroku, not in the build back.
heroku config:set GO_GIT_CRED__HTTPS__GITHUB__COM=FakePersonalAccessTokenHere

I found a gitlab issue that talks about replacing herokuish test pack directly with /bin/test build pack, but the issue seems never to have been resolved. (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/212689)
The project always seems to use herokuish (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/Test.gitlab-ci.yml)
Does anyone have an idea or am I going to have to overwrite the jobs to make a custom CI?

Here's the answer for the following developers.
Indeed is deprecated, everything is describe here : https://www.reddit.com/r/gitlab/comments/1atryl2/autodevops_still_maintained/?rdt=50911

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
